# The easiest way to insert multiple tables from one form

Tags: laravel

in laravel i want to insert into two tables the data from one form.

my forms are:

```
<input type="text" name="name"class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="age"class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="sex"class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="location"class="form-control">
```

i want to insert the `name`, `age`, and `sex` to table `details`. and input `location` to table `locations`

`location` model `belongsTo` `detail` model.

how to insert them at the same time? and how to automatically match the `id` of `detail` with `detail_id` of `location`?

i have search but too difficult to follow. i wish there's an easy way to follow.

Comment: save to details at first and then location. what's the problem.

Comment: I have try several way but still cant get it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't show us your model relationships and what you have in your controller so far.
But assuming your models are correctly related and your table field names are the same names as your form names, you could try this in your controller:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
  {
  $detail = new detail();
  $detail->name = $request->input("name");
  $detail->age = $request->input("age");
  $detail->sex = $request->input("sex");
  $detail->save();

 $location = new location();
 $location->detail_id = $detail->id;
 $location->location = $request->input("location");
 $location->save();
 }
```

hope this help.

Comment: Thanks i will try first

Comment: It give blank page. Please help.

Comment: check your data base, there is no redirect route here that's why it's black page

Comment: redirect your page after saving. add this `return view(wherever page you want it to be redirected);`

Comment: How to accepting it? I am sorry iam new to this site

Comment: I find it. Thank you